# Is it possible to access an internet enabled cctv camera only over wifi

Tags: security, wifi

I want to buy some CCTV cameras and I'm wondering if I can get an internet enabled one and access it from my own computer/iPad/phone only over wifi? Is this possible? Or does it have to be connected to the internet?

Comment: You should be able to access it over WiFi, and most require you to set them up via a local network. To disable internet viewing, you simply block the IP from outside access (use a static IP for the CCTV). Your system you purchase should have instructions for that.

Comment: @Jeff Cates this should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access it over WiFi, and most require you to set them up via a local network. To disable internet viewing, you simply block the IP from outside access (use a static IP for the CCTV). Your system you purchase should have instructions for that. – Jeff Cates 2 days ago

Comment: However, you may also want to view your camera from your mobile phone, anywhere in the world, in which case, assigning an IP address that only you have access to, would allow you to do that. Be sure that the cameras you buy comes with the application that allows you to do this. Not all do!